LaTeX to PNG Conversion Fails in Docker Container but Works in Local Development Environment
LaTeX to PNG Conversion Issue: Docker vs Local Environment
Problem Summary
A Python project that converts LaTeX equations to base64-encoded PNG images works perfectly in a local development environment (devcontainer) but fails when run inside a Docker container. In the Docker environment, the conversion process produces 1x1 pixel images instead of the expected output.
The following Python function handles the LaTeX to base64 conversion:
def latex_to_base64(
    latex_string: str,
    transparent: bool = True,
    scale: float = 1.0,
) -> str:
    unicode_to_latex = {
        "π": r"\pi",
        "α": r"\alpha",
        "β": r"\beta",
        "θ": r"\theta",
    }

    for unicode_char, latex_equiv in unicode_to_latex.items():
        latex_string = latex_string.replace(unicode_char, latex_equiv)

    logger.debug("Converted LaTeX string: {latex_string}", latex_string=latex_string)

    buf = io.BytesIO()

    try:
        logger.debug("Rendering LaTeX to PNG...")
        preview(
            latex_string,
            output="png",
            viewer="BytesIO",
            outputbuffer=buf,
            euler=False,
            packages=("amsmath", "amssymb", "amsfonts", "latexsym", "tikz"),
            dvioptions=["-D", "300"],  # Increased DPI to generate larger output
        )
        logger.debug("LaTeX rendering completed successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Failed to render LaTeX to image: {error}", error=str(e))
        logger.error("LaTeX input: {latex_string}", latex_string=latex_string)
        raise

    buf.seek(0)
    raw_size = len(buf.getvalue())
    logger.debug("Raw PNG output size: {size} bytes", size=raw_size)

    try:
        logger.debug("Processing the rendered image...")
        with Image.open(buf) as img:
            logger.debug("Image size before processing: {size}", size=img.size)

            if img.size[0] == 1 and img.size[1] == 1:
                raise ValueError("Rendered image has only (1, 1) size, which is too small.")

            img_with_alpha = img.convert("RGBA")

            if transparent:
                logger.debug("Applying transparency to the image...")
                datas = img_with_alpha.getdata()
                newData = [
                    (255, 255, 255, 0)
                    if item[0] > 240 and item[1] > 240 and item[2] > 240
                    else item
                    for item in datas
                ]
                img_with_alpha.putdata(newData)

            if scale != 1.0:
                logger.debug("Rescaling the image by a factor of {scale}", scale=scale)
                new_size = tuple(int(dim * scale) for dim in img_with_alpha.size)
                img_with_alpha = img_with_alpha.resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS)

            buf = io.BytesIO()
            img_with_alpha.save(buf, format="PNG")
            logger.debug("Image processing completed successfully.")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Failed to process the image: {error}", error=str(e))
        raise

    base64_string = base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
    logger.debug("Base64 encoding completed successfully.")

    return base64_string

The following error log is generated in the Docker container and the next one in my local enviroment (same code)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-03 22:22:39 | Converted LaTeX string: \begin{equation*}
\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \sum_{i=0}^n w_i f(x_i)
\end{equation*}
DEBUG    | 2024-09-03 22:22:39 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-03 22:22:40 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-03 22:22:40 | Raw PNG output size: 103 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-03 22:22:40 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-03 22:22:41 | Image size before processing: (1, 1)
ERROR    | 2024-09-03 22:22:41 | Failed to process the image: Rendered image has
only (1, 1) size, which is too small.
ERROR    | 2024-09-03 22:22:41 | Error converting LaTeX to image: Rendered image
has only (1, 1) size, which is too small.

DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:51 | Converted LaTeX string: $f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1$
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:51 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Raw PNG output size: 3426 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image size before processing: (399, 53)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Converted LaTeX string: $[0, 2]$
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Raw PNG output size: 1429 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image size before processing: (87, 50)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Converted LaTeX string: $\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \frac{h}{3} $
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Raw PNG output size: 8516 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image size before processing: (830, 67)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Converted LaTeX string: $h = (b - a) / 2$
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Raw PNG output size: 3158 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image size before processing: (283, 50)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Converted LaTeX string: $h$
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Raw PNG output size: 623 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image size before processing: (25, 36)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Converted LaTeX string: $f(a)$
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:52 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Raw PNG output size: 1625 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Image size before processing: (87, 50)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Converted LaTeX string: $f(a + h)$
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Raw PNG output size: 2309 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Image size before processing: (175, 50)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Converted LaTeX string: $f(b)$
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Rendering LaTeX to PNG...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | LaTeX rendering completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Raw PNG output size: 1627 bytes
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Processing the rendered image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Image size before processing: (82, 50)
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Applying transparency to the image...
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Rescaling the image by a factor of 0.4
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Image processing completed successfully.
DEBUG    | 2024-09-04 10:36:53 | Base64 encoding completed successfully.

The devcontainer.json file:
{
   ...
  
  "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:3.10-buster",

  "postCreateCommand": "sudo sh .devcontainer/setup.sh",

  ...
}

The setup.sh script:
#!/bin/bash
...
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -y \
    build-essential wkhtmltopdf libmagic1 libgl1 libglib2.0-0 \
    poppler-utils graphviz graphviz-dev patchelf libasound2 \
    libpango1.0-0 fonts-dejavu texlive-latex-extra dvipng \
    cm-super texlive-fonts-recommended
...

The Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Builder
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye AS builder

...

# Install system dependencies and UV
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -LsSf https://astral.sh/uv/install.sh | sh

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH" \
    UV_SYSTEM_PYTHON=1

# Copy only necessary files for dependency installation
COPY pyproject.toml uv.lock ./

# Install dependencies
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/uv \
    uv pip install --system --no-cache-dir --compile-bytecode -r pyproject.toml

# Install NLTK data (including punkt and stopwords)
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt stopwords -d /usr/share/nltk_data

# Stage 2: Runner
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install full LaTeX distribution and other system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libmagic1 \
    libgl1 \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    poppler-utils \
    graphviz \
    libpango1.0-0 \
    fonts-dejavu \
    texlive-fonts-recommended \
    texlive-generic-recommended \
    texlive-latex-extra \
    texlive-fonts-extra \
    dvipng \
    texlive-latex-recommended \
    texlive-base \
    texlive-pictures \
    texlive-lang-cyrillic \
    texlive-science \
    cm-super \
    texlive-generic-extra \
    wkhtmltopdf \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    GRAPHVIZ_DOT="/usr/bin/dot" \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    NLTK_DATA=/usr/share/nltk_data

# Copy installed packages from builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/nltk_data /usr/share/nltk_data

EXPOSE 8967

# Use Uvicorn to run the application
CMD ["uvicorn", "cortex.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8967", "--workers", "4"]


What could be causing the LaTeX to PNG conversion to fail in the Docker container while working fine in the local development environment?
Are there any additional dependencies or configurations that should be added to the Docker container to resolve this issue?
Any other tips on how can I better debug this?

Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

please don't delete and repost your question. If you would like to make changes, you can edit it instead.
